# Switch webdriverIO between Desktop Browser and Mobile App

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, appium, webdriver-io

I want automate a scenario which starts with Desktop chrome after performing certain action need to switch to Mobile app and validate the data in the Mobile App.

Currently Im using separate scenario to perform these test. Is it possible to load 2 driver in single session and switch at runtime ?

Using Webdriverio Typescript with Cucumber and Appium plugin for Mobile Automation